# Open VBS from hyperlink

Tags: vbscript

I created a hyperlink in a pdf, this hyperlink is tied to vbs script, until this step all ok. When I run the script manually (double click), the script does that I want (open telnet connection). The problem is when I run the script through the hyperlink, CMD show the message " "telnet" is not recognized as an internal or external command". Please, Can anyone tell me why occurs that??

This is the script:

```
    Dim WshShell, regexp
    set regular = New RegExp

    direccion = inputbox("Ingresa ip del equipo:")

    ' Set pattern.
    regular.Pattern = "^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$" 
    ' Set case insensitivity.
    regular.IgnoreCase = True  
    ' Set global applicability. 
    regular.Global = True   

    if regular.test(direccion) = TRUE then
      set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
      WshShell.run "cmd.exe"
      WScript.Sleep 1000
      'Send commands to the window as needed - IP and commands need to be customized
      'Step 1 - Telnet to remote IP'
      WshShell.SendKeys "telnet " & direccion
      WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
      WScript.Sleep 1000
    else
    msgbox "Ingresa una ip válida"
    end if
```

Comment: Something strange is happening, when I run the script manually (double click), in the task manager appear "Windows command processor", but when I run the script through the hyperlink (pdf file) in the task manager appear "Windows command processor(32 bits)", I think the problem maybe is related with that, but I dont know how solve it. Any idea??

Answer (score 1):

probably working directory not set correctly.

try

```
WshShell.SendKeys "c:\windows\system32\telnet.exe " & direccion
```

p.s: you're doing it wrong. "sendkeys" is somehow understandable when telnet terminal is already running, but there is no reason to be manually sending keys to the standard command prompt.

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestion, but the issue presists. With regard to "Sendkeys", I'm new with that, which is the correct form or method I should use?

Answer (score 0):

Telnet isn't in my Windows 10 and 8. But anyway if you have "telnet" command couldn't you do:

```
WshShell.run "cmd.exe /k telnet"
```

That should work and saves space.

Comment: Thanks, but not work. From the start, in all my attempts, CMD always shows the message: 
    '\\10.1.2.112\Networks and Services' CMD.EXE was started with the 
    above path as the current directory. UNC paths are not supported. 
    Defaulting to Windows directory. 'telnet' is not recognized as an 
    internal or external command,operable program or batch file.